# Difference between installing ROS from source and already-built one

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know what is the difference between installing ROS from source and "already-built" one. Despite knowing that as mentioned in the web page that the one that "already-built" is more efficient over the other, what is its limitation. I have also once heard from somebody telling that the best practice if we are developing something (not only using it) is to use the one built from source. Is that one right?

Thanks in advance.

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11342/difference-between-installing-ros-from-source-and-already-built-one/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By taking the pre-built packages from the repositories, they're by default read-only. This means that if you want to modify them, you'd need to change the permissions on every file.

The reason that they're read-only, however, is because the packages downloaded from the repositories (the pre-built packages) are the stable, maintained versions of the code. Occasionally, updates will be released. These updates will overwrite any local modifications to the packages, but will provide you with the latest stable builds.

Building from source, on the other hand, always gives you the most up-to-date version of each package. Checking out the source code also gives the code default read/write permissions, and it won't ever be updated, unless you do it manually. Checking out from source gives you more control over versions, modifications, etc.

The choice is really up to you. It really depends what you intend to do with the code. I hope this helps to clarify it a bit. I can't guarantee that this is a comprehensive list, but this is just my 2 cents.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-09-28**:
Thanks a lot for sharing your experience..

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-09-28**:
I use the pre-build binaries for most applications. I have my own code that I've written for my specific application, and then I use ROS packages for navigation, msgs, visualization, plugins, simulator, etc. I've created a few forks of ROS packages as well.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-09-28**:
@DimitriProsser: Just want to know, are using the pre-built binaries?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Source code is the human-readable and editable representation of a ROS package (or any other computer program). You need that for making changes to the program.

In most cases, some form of translation is required before a source program can be run on a computer. That is often called *building* the program. In ROS, `rosmake` will build any source package.

For relatively recent versions of Ubuntu Linux, the ROS community provides pre-built packages in native Ubuntu format. Those packages are usually easier and less error-prone to install.

Most ROS packages depend on other ROS packages for needed interfaces. For them, installing pre-built binary packages makes sense.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll save yourself a great deal of time (and a fair amont of pain) if you use pre-built binary packages wherever you can. As has been pointed out above, this won't work for packages you're currently coding on; those need to be recompiled every time you change something.

For things you aren't actively changing, having the pre-built binaries can save you a lot of time (building some of them takes hours) and guarantees that you're coding against the very same version of ROS that the rest of us are using, thereby making sure your code is portable.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1